# Number sequences: 6X000X9, 700XX08,00000015,?,00000015

Tags: number-sequence, letter-sequence

Here is the question:

6X000X9，700XX08，00000015，？，00000015，？，00000015

This question actually comes from the puzzles made by my friend. He gave me his puzzles recently but I couldn't figure it out. Any clues?

[image: Intro]

[image: Q8-14]

Hint1

> For question 10, odd terms are comprised of 1234567890

Hint2

> For question 11, the first number is 6,7,8,9,10

Hint3

> For question 13, odd terms are comprised of 123456

Comment: Ah btw, do you need us to solve the first $2$ questions mentioned or all of those questions in the image?

Comment: Any correct answer to any of the questions will be accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Partial for 10:

> Second ? is 3690147258 (left shift twice odd terms)

Comment: Yes, the difficult part is the even terms