# Number Sequence Series-Question 2

Tags: calculation-puzzle, number-sequence

I want to share a question that is created by myself.

I will give a hint in 24 hours and my answer in 3 days given that nobody could answer my question.

Here is my number sequence:

**1441,2882,5764,?,103840**

If you guys want some extremely challenging questions. Please check these two questions posted by me.

[Number sequences: 000, X00... and 6X000X9, 700XX08](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/84014/number-sequences-000-x00-and-6x000x9-700xx08)

[What are the alphabets in the question mark?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83925/what-are-the-alphabets-in-the-question-mark)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is:

> $10439$

Because

> If we sum the number and its reverse, we have the next number.
>  Hence $5764+4675=10439$

Comment: Yes correct, congrats.