# Number Sequence Series-Question 3

Tags: calculation-puzzle, number-sequence

I want to share a series of questions that are created by myself.

I will give a hint in 24 hours and my answer in 3 days given that nobody could answer my question.

Here is my number sequence:

**2020,1436,7575,?,23111311**

If you guys want some extremely challenging questions. Please check these two questions posted by me.

[Number sequences: 000, X00... and 6X000X9, 700XX08](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/84014/number-sequences-000-x00-and-6x000x9-700xx08)

[What are the alphabets in the question mark?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83925/what-are-the-alphabets-in-the-question-mark)

Update

Hint1:

> The logic is related to 1234

Hint2:

> Separate the digits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The missing number is

> $69811$

Procedure for getting from one step to the next

> **1.** Separate out the digits (e.g, $2020 \rightarrow 2,0,2,0$). 
>  **2.** Reverse the sequence (e.g, $2,0,2,0 \rightarrow 0,2,0,2$). 
>  **3.** Add $1$ to the first digit, $2$ to the second, $\ldots n$ to the $n$th (e.g, $0,2,0,2 \rightarrow 1,4,3,6$). 
>  **4.** Recombine the digits (e.g, $1,4,3,6 \rightarrow 1436$).

Other cases, step-by-step

> $1436 \rightarrow 7575$ 
>  **1.** $1436 \rightarrow 1,4,3,6$ 
>  **2.** $1,4,3,6 \rightarrow 6,3,4,1$ 
>  **3.** $6,3,4,1 \rightarrow 7,5,7,5$ 
>  **4.** $7,5,7,5 \rightarrow 7575$ 
>  $7575 \rightarrow 69811$ 
>  **1.** $7575 \rightarrow 7,5,7,5$ 
>  **2.** $7,5,7,5 \rightarrow 5,7,5,7$ 
>  **3.** $5,7,5,7 \rightarrow 6,9,8,11$ 
>  **4.** $6,9,8,11 \rightarrow 69811$ 
>  $69811 \rightarrow 23111311$ 
>  **1.** $69811 \rightarrow 6,9,8,1,1$ 
>  **2.** $6,9,8,1,1 \rightarrow 1,1,8,9,6$ 
>  **3.** $1,1,8,9,6 \rightarrow 2,3,11,13,11$ 
>  **4.** $2,3,11,13,11 \rightarrow 23111311$

Comment: Yes, that is correct! I was about to post my own answer...I strongly recommend you to try the challenging ones!