# Number Sequence Series-Question 5

Tags: calculation-puzzle, number-sequence

This a series of questions that are created by myself.

I will give a hint in 24 hours and my answer in 3 days given that nobody could answer my question.

Here is question 5:

**342,765,?,242325** (It seems like it is easy and might have several answers but there is only one answer and the logic must be the neatest)
$$$$
If you guys want some extremely challenging questions. Please check these two questions posted by me.

[Number sequences: 000, X00... and 6X000X9, 700XX08](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/84014/number-sequences-000-x00-and-6x000x9-700xx08)

[What are the alphabets in the question mark?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83925/what-are-the-alphabets-in-the-question-mark)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> $131112$. If the number is $abc$, the new number is $(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)$. The number keeps these as 'single digits', hence the next number is $(13+11)(11+12)(12+13)=242325$.

Comment: I hope this is a well-explained answer (+1)

Comment: Congrats! This is the right answer.