# Number Sequence Series-Question 6

Tags: calculation-puzzle, number-sequence

This a series of questions that are created by myself.

Since question 6 is not that difficult I will not give any hint to you guys.

Enjoy the test.

Here is question 6:

**2,6,8,7,5,3,?**
$$$$
If you guys want some extremely challenging questions. Please check these two questions posted by me.

[Number sequences: 000, X00... and 6X000X9, 700XX08](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/84014/number-sequences-000-x00-and-6x000x9-700xx08)

[What are the alphabets in the question mark?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83925/what-are-the-alphabets-in-the-question-mark)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer is,

> $\frac{8}{5}$

Reason

> Add first two terms and divide by 1 to get third term ( $\frac{2+6}{1} = 8$)
> $$$$
> Similarly, (2nd term + 3rd term )/2 = 4th term ($\frac{6+8}{2} = 7$)
> $$$$
> and $\frac{7+8}{3} = 5$ and $\frac{7+5}{4} = 3$
> $$$$
> Thus, $$\frac{5+3}{5} = \frac{8}{5}$$